# Method for parsing a txt file

Tags: c#, parsing

I wish to create a parser for poker hand history. I want to extract information like *who is the button?*

How might I approach this? Here's a sample history file:

```
#Game No : 11460450069 
***** Hand History for Game 11460450069 *****
NL Texas Hold'em $1 USD Buy-in Trny:67308896 Level:8  Blinds-Antes(600/1.200 -50) - Wednesday, February 22, 05:48:56 EST 2012
Table Turbo #2533048 (Real Money)
Seat 5 is the button
Total number of players : 2/10 
Seat 5: NAME( 2,898 )
Seat 2: NAME( 17,102 )
Trny:67308896 Level:8 
Blinds-Antes(600/1.200 -50)
NAMEposts ante [50]
NAMEposts ante [50]
** Dealing down cards **
Dealt to NAME[  Th Js ]
NAME is all-In  [2,248]
NAME calls [1,648]
** Dealing Flop ** [ 3h, 2d, 9s ]
** Dealing Turn ** [ Jd ]
** Dealing River ** [ Ad ]
NAME shows [ 5s, Kc ]high card Ace.
NAME shows [ Th, Js ]a pair of Jacks.
NAME wins 5,796 chips from the main pot with a pair of Jacks.
NAME finished in 2 place and won $2.55 USD.
```

Comment: Looks like a good job for [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File formats are specification of structure of a file. They're usually in binary but in your case and in many other cases, they're text. The first thing you need to do is decide on the structure of your document and then read it like by line. You can also use tools that make this process much easier, like those based on Parse Grammar rules. I think ANTLR, as mentioned by Philip in his answer, is one of those tools...